# Serializing ASP.NET style JSON dates with Python

Tags: python, asp.net-mvc, json

I need to call a web service written in ASP.NET MVC that accepts JSON as input. The JSON includes a date field. ASP.NET expects dates to be serialized like this:

```
\/Date(1371071410)\/
```

(Note: this is a single backslash followed by a single forwardslash; in essence, an escaped forward slash, which is valid JSON, although you normally wouldn't do that.)

I'm trying to convince Python's json library to encode datetime like this, but no luck so far. Basically, if I try to encode it like above, the json library escapes the backslash, turning the string into:

```
\\/Date(1371071409)\\/
```

(Note the double backslashes.)

This makes ASP.NET's deserializer refuse to parse it as a date.

What can I do to prevent Python's json library to avoid escaping the backslashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the string encoding happens in the `json.encoder` module, more specifically in the [`encode_basestring`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/464e8fd7300d/Lib/json/encoder.py#l33), and [`encode_basestring_ascii`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/464e8fd7300d/Lib/json/encoder.py#l64) functions.

So to change how a string is encoded, you could wrap these functions to return the representation you need.

Or, if you look at how the encoder [encodes an `int`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/464e8fd7300d/Lib/json/encoder.py#l404), you could subclass `int` with a custom string representation, as your Date here isn't much more then an int anyway:

```
import json

class IntDate(int):
    def __str__(self):
        return r'"\/Date(%s)\/"' % super(IntDate, self).__str__()

print(json.dumps({'date': IntDate(1371071409)}))
```

prints:

```
{"date": "\/Date(1371071409)\/"}
```